# React - Enzyme Test - How to check class after simulate a click

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

I am new in React Enzyme testing. I'd like check class name after click button, and I am getting empty class for enzyme shallow wrapper.

**Button.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import style from './styles.module.scss';

export interface ButtonPropTypes {
  title?: string;
}

const Button = ({ title }: ButtonPropTypes) => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div
      className={cx(style.container, {
        [style.active]: active,
      })}
      onClick={() => setActive(!active)}
    >
      {title}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Button;
```

Button.test.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow, ShallowWrapper } from 'enzyme';

import Button from './index';

let wrapper: ShallowWrapper;

beforeEach(() => {
  wrapper = shallow(<Button titie="Toggle Me"/>);
});

describe('<Button />', () => {
  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(Button).toBeDefined();
  });

  it('should match snapshot', () => {
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

  it('should button toggle work', () => {
    wrapper.find('div').first().simulate('click');
    console.log(wrapper.debug()); // log looks like "<div class=""> ... </div>"
    expect(wrapper.find('.active').length).toBe(0);
  });
});
```

Please let me know how can I check the actual wrapper class has active characters when its status is active through the toggle action.

Cheers!

Comment: Hi @Steven.J.

Please take a look below link to make your test wrapper inject css classes when you are using scss with css modules!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59824958/can-i-use-enzymes-hasclass-feature-with-react-components-importing-css-files

I hope this could help you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your project inject css classnames adding below config in jest.config.js file.

```
moduleNameMapper: {
  "^.+\\.(css|less|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
}
```

In your test file, you can check class name like below.

```
...

it('should toggle action work', () =>. {
    wrapper.simulate('click');
    expect(wrapper.find('.active').length).toBe(1);
    
    wrapper.simulate('click');
    expect(wrapper.find('.active').length).toBe(0);
});

...
```

Good luck!